# Document.Open() is not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

So, I have a button where if the person's username and password is correct, it will notify you, then it will redirect to another page. The first thing works, but it will not redirect you to the page.

Here is the code of the webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Siur</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
///////////////////////////Login System///////////////////////////
function getCookie(){
  var whole, username, password, splitting, actual,user, pass;
  whole = document.cookie;
  whole = whole.split(';');
  username = whole[0];
  password = whole[1];
  actual = password.split('=');
  user = actual[0];
  pass = actual[1];
  alert(user + password);
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
  var c_value=value + "; 
  pass="+document.getElementById('passwordText').value;
  document.cookie="=" + value + "; 
  pass="+document.getElementById('passwordText').value;
  alert(document.cookie);
  getCookie();
}

function url(url){
  document.open(url);
}

function checkCookie(){
  var whole, username, password, splitting, actual,user, pass;
  whole = document.cookie;
  whole = whole.split(';');
  username = whole[0];
  password = whole[1];
  actual = password.split('=');
  user = actual[0];
  pass = actual[1];
  if (document.getElementById('usernameText').value !=null &&
      document.getElementById('usernameText').value!="" &&
      document.getElementById('passwordText').value == pass) {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
    document.open('search_webpage.html');
  }
  else{
    alert('Incorrect username or password.');
  }
}
//////////////////////////////End of Login system////////////////////////////////////
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table width=100% height=30 background="nav.png" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td >
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
          <label for="searchBox"></label>
          IN-DEV 0.1

        </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<img src="logo.png" width="206" height="147" />
  <p>-Where everything is at your finger tips-</p>
  <p>
    <label for="usernameText"><label>Username: </label></label>
    <input type="text" name="usernameText" id="usernameText" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="passwordText"><label>Password: </label></label>
    <input type="password" name="passwordText" id="passwordText" />
  </p>
</center>
<center>

<input type="submit" name="create" id="create" onclick="checkCookie()" value="Login" /> 
<input type="submit" name="check" id="check" onclick="setCookie(
 document.getElementById('usernameText').value,
 document.getElementById('passwordText').value,365);" value="Register" />
</p>
  <p><a href="http://blacklist.eff.org/">Fight SOPA now!</a></p>

  <p><!--[if lt IE 7]> 
  <div style=' clear: both; height: 59px; padding:0 0 0 15px; position: relative;'> <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
  <img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." />
  </a></div> <![endif]--><footer><font color="#CCCCCC">Copyright 2012, All Rights Reserved.</font></footer></p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all, its generally not a real good idea to use a variable name that also refers to a function. And I observed alot of issues in your basic HTML code, as the first stage itself try to write proper and follow the best practices.

for the following

```
function url(url){
      document.open(url); //is url the function or the variable?
}
```

Use as follows

```
function goto_url(url) {
  window.location.href = url; //I think this might be what you are looking for
}
```

On a totally seperate note, validating the user's password using javascript is like a bank asking you if your check is good before agreeing to cash it.

My apologies, I meant `window.location.href`, but could cause a history loop if they click the back button.. Perhaps better to use `window.location.replace(url)`

Answer (score 4):

`document.open()` is not used to go to a new URL. It is called when you use `document.write()`. It will clear the current page.

You want to use `window.location = 'http://example.com';`.